# How to migrate documents between Notes databases

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a Notes application where we have a Live version and Development version.  Something strange is occurring on the Live version and I wish to export the affected documents from Live to Development with the aim of using these for a work around.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use copy/paste:

1. select the documents in question in the live version
2. choose Edit - Copy
3. go to the development version
4. choose Edit - Paste

Comment: @PerHenrickLausten thanks for response.  Yes I tried that but when I go to the development version in Notes, highlight the relevant View and select Edit then paste, I am just presented with a long dialogue box with two buttons, Search and Cancel. I press Search the dialogue vanishes but the record is not in the view

Comment: It sounds like you are copying and pasting text and not the actual Notes documents. How are you copying from the live version?

Comment: @PerHenrickLausten By opening the relevant view finding the relevant document and left click on it and then on menu bar edit then copy

Comment: Hmm, that sounds correct. Do you have direct access to the live version from your Notes client (you are not opening the live version using e.g. a remote desktop)?

Comment: @PerHenrickLausten No not using remote desktop.  Just opening the Live version by using the Notes client on my laptop.  File, Open, Lotus Notes Application and finding it on the relevant server where it opens it and places it also on my Workspace

Comment: @PerHenrickLausten Ah!  Its working at least for a "real document".  Thanks Per.  What my issue is that the database is actually for an Xpages project and for an unknown reason occasionally duplicate documents are being created when a user creates a new Contract (the app is about Contracts).  I am trying create a workaround in Domino instead of tampering with the xpages that work on 99.99% of cases.  I want to copy the duplicates over to Dev to work with them to create a workaround but its the duplicates (Replication or save conflicts documents in Notes db) that won't copy over

Comment: Check the docs and see if there is a $KeepPrivate item in them. If the docs are marked to prevent copying, then the copy will fail. That would leave whatever was previously on the clipboard, which would explain why the paste brings up the search box.

Comment: @PerHenrickLausten so I suppose you have answered my question.  Thanks.  I will just have to find another way of working with this